# How to handle the necessity of interprocess communication in my Android application?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

My application requires me to periodically do the following:

1. Send periodic heartbeat information to a server, once per 15 seconds
2. Take periodic screen captures and send them to a server, once per 60 seconds
3. Send message to and poll the server for messages, once every 5 seconds

I've written the services for each of the items listed above but here is where I need help, communication between those services...

The heartbeat service needs to be able to:

1. Get some information from the screen capture service.
2. Queue a message with the messaging service.

The screen capture service needs to be able to do the following:

1. Fetch the current activity from my application
2. Queue a message with the messaging service.

The messaging service needs to be able to do the following:

1. Receive messages to queue up to be sent to the server from my application/services
2. Send messages received from the server to the application

With all of the communication pathways required, I'm wondering how to do that? Would I just bind my application to all of the services? Bind services to other services? Use some other from of communication?

I need all of those services to continue running/functioning even if my application isn't in the foreground.

Comment: First and foremost, the Android has no way of ensuring that *any* background apps keep running; it was never meant for daemons. Second, periodic server polling will kill the battery *and* the data plan. Third, it sounds outright spooky - what's with quiet screen captures?

Comment: Devices will be mounted in public, hard-wired to a power source and on a wifi network so battery life/consumption isn't a concern. The goal of the screen caps is for monitoring purposes to ensure the application is running correctly and to help with debugging.

Comment: Then Android is a very poor choice for an OS. Consider one of the slimmer flavors of Linux or Windows Embedded.

Comment: What I need cannot be done with Android then? I'm constrained by the desires of my employer so I don't have the luxury of better choices in this case.

Comment: I don't know the entirety of what you need, so I can't tell for sure. But Android is known for killing background apps with no forewarning. It's not a server OS, never was.

Comment: Not sure if this makes much of a difference or not but the app I'm trying to write is a launcher and will be set as the default launcher for the device and if the app is binding to the services in question wouldn't that keep things running somewhat how I intend?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41888/discussion-between-ryan-and-seva-alekseyev)

Comment: Taking screenshots for debugging purposes seems a real bad idea to me. It'll most likely introduce more bugs than it'll help you fix.

Comment: This question was [discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210819/bad-audit-once-again).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided [more info in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/13147676#13147676), but the general thrust is:

- use AlarmManager to schedule invokations of a broadcast receiver
- let the receiver re-schedule itself when invoked
- let the receiver send a command to the service (this will start the service, if it's not running already)
- let the service spin a thread
- do HTTP in the thread